# Mock up of Coat of Arms

Tags: idiom, motto

I want to make a coat of arms for my father in law, and we always refer to him doing anything with the phrase  - "**that'll do**". Is there a Latin phrase that this translates to? Google translate has suggested '*hoc faciam*' but reverse translating it changes the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but *that'll do* is slang/an idiom for that's enough (pretty much in the speaker's subjective point of view.)

- On one hand, we know little about slang Latin although vulgar and medieval Latin could somehow do the job. I'm no expert in any of those, although what I have is a quote from the Vulgate (Latin translation of the Bible from the IV century,) which is late Latin. At least it is not Classical, in which case you would have what is arguably the opposite of slang.
- On the other hand, *that'll do* in the sense of *that's enough* may have more than one reading, judging from what I read [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/that%27ll+do): from a soft *that's ok, thank you* to a hard *stop it!*. In the later case I would recommend Joonas' *satis*.

But what came to my mind is:

> **Sufficit** mihi

*Sufficit* is a conjugated form of the verb [sufficio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsufficio), which among its meanings includes: *to be sufficient, to suffice, avail for, meet the need of, satisfy*, and is attested in this sense in the Vulgate e.g. in [2 Cor 12, 9](https://www.biblestudytools.com/vul/2-corinthians/12-9.html):

> *sufficit tibi gratia mea* // [My grace is enough for you](http://www.catholic.org/bible/book.php?bible_chapter=12&id=54#9),

It is in 3rd person singular, meaning that the *it* (as in *it*'s enough) is (arguably) explicit. The cite above also implies that you can use the personal pronoun in dative to remark for whom is something enough, hence *sufficit mihi*-it's enough for me.

Now, using the first person in a real coat of arms would be daring, but given it's a satirical one, it's more of a matter of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a perfect match, but here are two alternatives to express that the situation is good enough:

1. ***Satis.*** — "Enough." (See [this dictionary entry](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2052897) for *satis*.)
2. ***Satisfacit.*** — "[It] suffices." (See [this dictionary entry](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2052902) for the verb *satisfacio*.)

A similar effect to the first alternative is reached with the adverb [*sufficienter*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2057342), but it's rarer.
However, the tone might be better, as *satis* can be read as "too much" or "stop", whereas *sufficienter* is more neutral.

Comment: "Satis" is pretty ambiguous: in fact, the first meaning that comes to my mind is "enough!" as in "stop!" The first thing that came to my mind is a Plautine "sat mi est"

Comment: @brianpck Fair enough. I updated my explanation. *Satis* can be read in the intended way, but it's open to less welcome interpretations as well.